# Invalid column name on sum

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to perform sql statement

```
select buyer, issuer, ident, sum(qnty) as sum1
from palete
where sum1 <> 0
group by buyer, issuer, ident
```

and I am getting error 
Invalid column name 'sum1'.

Problem is that I am getting a lot of results, so I would like to avoid these results where sum1 is 0.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Could you post the table definition of `palete`?

Answer (score 6):

Alternate, without the subquery:

```
select buyer, issuer, ident, sum(qnty) as sum1 
from palete 
group by buyer, issuer, ident 
having sum(qnty) <> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Aliases aren't recognised in where clauses. You need to do it like this:

```
select buyer, issuer, ident, sum(qnty) as sum1 
from palete 
group by buyer, issuer, ident 
having sum(qnty) <> 0
```

Comment: can't use aggregate in the where clause

Comment: You cannot have aggregates on the where clause. Use HAVING

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
(
  select buyer, issuer, ident, sum(qnty) as sum1 from palete group by buyer, issuer, ident
) as T1 where T1.sum1 <> 0
```

Comment: You are right, it works. But why nesting when you can use having?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use HAVING clause instead of WHERE clause.

The SQL HAVING clause is used in conjunction with the SELECT clause to specify a search condition for a group or aggregate. The HAVING clause behaves like the WHERE clause, but is applicable to groups - the rows in the result set representing groups. In contrast the WHERE clause is applied to individual rows, not to groups.

Hope this helps.